# Color points according to the range R

Tags: r, colors, range, col

I am plotting combination of two matrices with pairs, and want to specify the color for the range of rows. I came with solution that seems ugly for me. Any suggestions to directly specify the range of rows (or/and columns) to be colored according to specified colors?
Thank you in advance!

```
# C - is combination of two matrices A and B
C <- rbind(A,B)
C_f <- as.factor(c(rep("label1",nrow(A)),rep("label2",nrow(B))))
pairs(C, col=c("red", "blue")[C_f])

# EDIT: added matrix generation as  thelatemail asked
A<-matrix(sample(1:100,rep=T),10,10)
B<-matrix(sample(1:200,rep=T),20,10)
C<-rbind(A,B)
```

Comment: Can you add some example `A` and `B` data using `dput` or with a `matrix` function call please? Otherwise we're all guessing how this is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to just do

```
  pairs(C, col=c("red", "blue")[rep(1:2, c(nrow(A), nrow(B)))])
```

and eliminate the second line  (ie, no need for `C_f`)

Comment: any ideas how too make that with providing the ranges directly? (thank's by the way the solution worked perfectly).

Comment: @chupvl -- Try this: `col = c('red', 'blue')[match(C_f, c('label1', 'label2'))]`

Comment: @chupvl, what do you mean by providing the ranges directly?

Comment: for example I have matrix that came not from combination of 2 or several, and I want to say color rows 1:10 in red, rows 10:67 in blue, and all other in grey.